# How to use PHP to lookup a single value by using two keys?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, lookup

When I have a single key and I need a value.
I can do this single-key lookup by using a PHP `array`.

```
$data = array(1 => "one");
return $data[1];
```

I have a set of data where two keys are required to locate a single value.
What are the facilities to lookup a value with two keys?

```
return get_value[$key1, $key2]; //?
```

**Example of data:**

There are several testing facilities that are individually numbered `(1, 2, 3, 4, etc)`.  Each facility has set of products that it tests `(A, B, C, D)`.  Each facility has a peculiarity in how it sets field names in the database for each product.  Facility 1 testing product A uses fields `{x, y, z}` to get a set of graph points.  Facility 2 testing product A uses fields `{m, n, q}` to get a set or graph points.  The interface to get the graph points is the same, but the fields are different.  I need to have an abstraction to normalize the fields, no matter which testing facility and product that they test.

I am thinking of doing it by setting up an abstraction that looks up the required fields by using the two keys:  testing facility number and product to be tested.

```
[1, A] => {x, y, z}
[1, B] => {m, n, q}
[2, C] => {g, r, b}
etc
```

Comment: I think you had better show us an example of the data as currently I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Or do you mean `get_value[$key1][$key2];` But again we need to see what array you are processing to be of any real help here

Comment: When you have a array like array(1=>array(1=>"value")) you can access it with $data[1][1] and get the "value"

Comment: A key could be one value only, you can keep a concatenated value like this `$key1."---".$key2` and store the values in array and in order to get the value. Get the values like `$data[$key1."---".$key2]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I suppose it is a question how to store a value which is defined by two keys. Sure this can be a mutlidimensional array. But also something like `$array[$value1 . ':' . $value2]`

Comment: array has always 1 key assigned to an element but that element can be an array too then it's multidimensional

Comment: @Riggs, added example of data (high level)

Answer (score 4):

You should store the data like this:

```
$data = [
  1 => [
    'A' => {set of fields X},
    'B' => {set of fields Y},
  ],
  2 => [
    'C' => {set of fields Z}
  }
]
```

You can access the set of fields X like this: `$data[1]['A']`.

Answer (score 0):

I may also consider this:

```
$set1 = array('x', 'y', 'z');
$set2 = array('m', 'n', 'q');
standard_set = array('a', 'b', 'c');

if ($key1 === 1 && $key2 === 'A')
    return $set1;
else if ($key1 === 1 && $key2 === 'B')
    return $set2;
else
    return $standard_set;
```

Answer (score -1):

A key could have one value only, you can keep a concatenated value like this

```
$data = array($key1."---".$key2=>$firstValue);
```

and store the values in array. In order to get the values, you can get the values like

```
echo $data[$key1."---".$key2];
```

The concept is like composite key (as we have in databases) but you are just merging them into 1 value so that you can utilize it as a key

In your case:

```
$data = array('1'.'-'.'A'=>Whatever);
```

Comment: I like the concept of merging multiple keys into a single key to where you can then use various multiple established facilities to do a key => value lookup.  Why are there downvotes?

Comment: @Dennis probably because I answered right there before you edited your post with example